# 'to' versus 'in order to'

Tags: word-difference

Is it always possible to just use 'to' instead of 'in order to'?

What is actually the additional information provided by 'in order to'?

I understand *in order to* as meaning that the aforementioned action comes first (in order) and thus enables the subsequently mentioned action.

So we have the order: 1st action allows 2nd action.

But isn't this always the case, even when using 'to' in order to describe a following action that requires the aforementioned action?

I find it quite difficult to explain what I mean, particularly because I do not know what clauses that begin with 'in order to' are called. Cause/reason clauses, or something like that?

Comment: [This explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/ENGLISH/comments/s2xb4n/comment/hshmd22/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) is awesome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**in order to** communicates purpose or intent rather than timing. You can simply use **to** instead, and your sentence will be correct, but **in order to** makes explicit the actor's reasoning for performing the first action.

Answer (score 3):

*In order to*, as I see it, means "as a means to do/achieve...", and it can derive some other forms like "in order that", which has to be followed by a sentence.

Mostly you can use *to* instead of *in order to* in a sentence without making any grammatical mistakes. But *to* doesn't necessarily convey the meaning of "with an intention" as much as *in order to* does.

Answer (score 0):

"to" is part of the infinitive in English & does not necessarily  connote purpose/intention. So:

Q: Where are you planning to go this summer?

A: I am planning to go to Rome.

Comment: This is a little confusing.  While "to go" is the infinitive, "to Rome" is a dative noun.  You may wish to expand your answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

The usage affects the meaning depending on whether the clause refers to the subject or the object:

> He sent the kids to his mother's house to have some  peace (so that they could have some peace)
> He sent the kids to his mother's house in order to have some  peace (so that he could have some peace)

Comment: As far as I can see both your sentences mean the same. Can you edit to elaborate on why you think they are different?

Answer (score 0):

Good Question, Compare the sentences:

To win, we must work together

In Order to win, we must work together

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners. In our answers here, you have to actually answer the question. Your answer here, however, sounds like the beginning of a dialogue or a prompt. Also, I don't see how it contributes anything to the question, since the OP already seems to know that "in order" is often optional, so an example of this won't reveal anything.