# What's the difference in meaning between “challenge” + infinitives(to V.) vs. gerund(V. ing)

Tags: word-usage, difference, infinitives, present-continuous

I have a problem in comparing these two sentences.

1. > DDP challenges protecting inventor's ideas.
2. > DDP challenges to protect inventor's ideas.

Translation in my book says (1) means DDP opposes protecting of ideas, but (2) means DDP strives to protects.

Firstly, I don't know this translation is right or not.

Secondly, if it is right, why does this difference occur? just from the difference in using ~ing or to behind the verb 'challenge'?

Comment: What is the source of these sentences?  They look like newspaper headlines, which makes it more complicated.

Comment: @stangdon It's just from a problem in the test performed in my region. And it is one of the choices that problem gives. So.. the full problem is
'Q. Which is correct according to the talk?
(c) DDP challenges protecting inventor's ideas.'

Comment: For reference, the talk says about why the DDP is developed.

Comment: What do you mean by: translation in my book?? I thought it was in English. What is: according to the talk? Do you mean speech? Or  a talk given by a person? I find these questions very confusing.

Comment: @Lambie My book is one of the English workbook for preparing English test, and it gives translation from English to Korean. And it says like that (in Korean). Because I thought the talks said DDP is made for protecting the inventor's ideas, I chose the choice 'DDP challenges protecting inventor's idea'. But translation says it means (1), not (2).

Comment: I@Lee TY It gives the translation into Korean and you are back-translating it for us? Is that right?

Comment: @Lambie Yes, it's right.

Comment: The explanation for 1) is right. As for 2), the explanation would be right if the sentence read: DDP challenges [direct object] to protect inventor's idea. Without a direct object, the sentence is very iffy. to challenge someone or something to [do] something. [please note, fyi: when referring to something someone ***just said***, we say: Yes, that's right. and not: It's right. :)

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for explanation. I understand why it should be. Because my mother tongue is not English, I have many awkward points in my using English. Thank you for pinpointing that.

Comment: @Lee TY In state of New Jersey, they say: Fuhgeddaboudit! [forget about it], often used as a joke but it comes from people actually saying that. Don't worry about awkward points. Using this/that etc. in speech is kinda [kind of] difficult. I often wonder if these books used overseas are even edited or proofread by actual English speakers. najung-e bwa. :)

Comment: @Lambie I wonder that point, too. But I'm just one of the students. Thank you for answer and see you later ! 감사합니다!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['to' versus 'in order to'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11517/to-versus-in-order-to)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for reference. I'll check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your book is correct, and the sentences mean what it says they do.

But I can understand why this is confusing!  Let's look at the parts that are different.

> DDP challenges **protecting** inventor's ideas
>   DDP challenges **to protect** inventor's ideas

Usually, the gerund (*verb*-ing) and the infinitive (to *verb*) mean very similar things.  For example, in

> I like **reading** books
>   I like **to read** books

*reading* and *to read* mean almost exactly the same thing.

But **to** can also mean "for the purpose of" or "to achieve".  For example, in

> Sally exercises **to stay fit**

*to stay fit* means "for the purpose of staying fit".

In the first sentence, "DDP challenges **protecting** inventor's ideas", DDP is challenging something.  What is that thing?  *Protecting*, meaning the act of protecting the inventor's ideas.  So DDP is challenging that act.

In the second sentence, "DDP challenges **to protect** inventor's ideas", we see "DDP challenges *to*", which means that DDP challenges *for some reason*, or *to achieve some purpose*.  What is that purpose? *To protect the inventor's ideas.*

Comment: Thank you for perfect explanation. I understand the meaning of the infinitive (I think).

Comment: We often get people posting here who aren't clear about the difference between a *noun phrase* and an actual *sentence*. OP's first example strikes me as somewhat unusual phrasing for a sentence, but it wouldn't be all that odd as a noun phrase in a context such as ***DDP challenges protecting inventor's ideas** include the Joe Bloggs vs Microsoft case last year, where DDP successfully argued for Mr Bloggs to be recognised as the rightful owner of certain code unlawfully plagiarised by MS.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yeah, the examples are still somewhat odd as full sentences, which is why I originally asked about newspaper headlines.  But that's another can of worms.

Comment: @stangdon: I think your answer is all good stuff, but looking at this page again now I think the question itself might essentially be a duplicate, so I'm gonna flag it up and see if anyone else agrees. (If they do, let that be a lesson to you not to rattle my cage by responding to my comments! :)