# These terms are important for me to work here happily

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, prepositional-phrases, infinitives, complements

Can I use infinitive clauses in that way?

> 1-) These terms are important **for me to work here happily**.
>
> 2-) These terms are important **to work here happily**.(If it is obvious that I am talking about myself, can we omit "*for me*"?)
>
> 3-) These features are necessary **for this game to work properly**.
>
> 4-) Body language is necessary **to communicate with someone correctly**.

If this usage is correct, could you please explain what these infinitives' functions are?

I don't think that the examples 2-4 are adjective complements because I have never seen a source/website/book saying that "necessary and important" can have infinitive complements. (It is important/necessary to do something) is a different structure that is not the complement example, which is not the case.)

Finally, what are your thoughts? Are they grammatically OK?

Comment: You might hear similar examples of **important** from some native speakers  but I consider those sentences to be better suited to an **if**-clause: **... important, if I'm going to work here happily**.  Because **important** doesn't rise to the level of necessary, it is  **for** that introduces the conditionality, and that's why you cannot omit **for** (and still convey the same meaning).

Comment: It is **not** obvious that you're talking about yourself, BTW, in the second sentence. But that's not really relevant to the issue, which is about the expression of the conditional nature of **these terms**.

Answer (score 0):

Reversing the order of your clauses might clarify the issue for you:

> For me to work here happily, these terms are important.
>
> <sup>in other words</sup> If I am going to work here happily, these terms are important.

And by **important** the speaker wants the listener to understand *"a necessary condition"*. But it doesn't really have that meaning.  **important** doesn't quite rise to **necessary** except in *double-talk*. That's OK. It's clear *contextually* from ***For* me to ...happily** that you're at least *threatening* a necessary condition, even though **important** doesn't quite rise to the level of "necessary condition".

But in the second sentence it is not clear that you're expressing a condition relative to yourself, relative to the speaker of the words. The infinitive clause could apply to **these terms**. For example:

> To work here smoothly, these terms must be adjusted. They might have worked in a factory without a labor union, but they won't work here, at least not "as is".

Because of that possibility the sentence goes off the rails when we reach **are important**:

> To work here happily, these terms are important.

Comment: Well, in that case, I would like to suggest using "for+gerund" instead of "infinitive". How about that? 
These terms are important for my working here happily.
These terms must be adjusted for working here smoothly.

Comment: Using **for** + gerund diminishes the conditional force.  The terms are not a necessary condition for your working there.  The sentence is actually quite vague. All we know is that the terms are important in some way related to your working there.  I consider such a sentence marginal:  *The terms are important for my working there.*  I don't really know what it means.

Answer (score -2):

1) Looks good. You could also say:

> These terms are important for me to be happy working here.

2) No, you need the *for me*, otherwise it denotes a generality that everyone feels.

3) Grammatically correct, but you need purpose here. You might also say:

> These features are necessary in order for this game to work properly.
>
> These features are necessary so that this game works properly.

4) I believe you need the *in order to* here. I would also say effectively instead of correctly.

> Body language is necessary *in order to* communicate with someone effectively.

see [to vs in order to](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11517/to-versus-in-order-to) and [so that or in order that](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/so-that-or-in-order-that)

Comment: Why did you get stuck in "in order to" ? I don't think that it is necessary. These features are necessary. There is no purpose here. The action that these features are necessary doesn't need any purpose. You can't ask "Why are they necessary?", but you can ask "For what are they necessary?". I don't agree with you.

Comment: You can use *to* when speaking instead of *in order to* in these cases, but if you want your thoughts to flow better, especially in writing, I would use the more specific terms here. You can say either *why are they necessary* or *what are they necessary for*.  I guess you don't have to agree with me.

Comment: You do not need "in order to" in either 3 or 4 to make it communicate your intended meaning OR to make it flow naturally. It's not wrong to add it in, but it doesn't change the meaning and it makes it flow *less* naturally, in my opinion.