# Where is the main verb of "the glossy skyscrapers that house hedge funds and investment banks look too polished?"

Tags: sentence-structure

> Hollywood has long been seduced by the world of high finance. All that money! All that power! **The glossy skyscrapers that house hedge funds and investment banks look too polished to contain American psychos and Wall Street wolves.** And yet, there they are—an assortment of memorable monsters, backstabbing and clawing their way to the top.[This Movie Plot Is the Stuff of HR Nightmares](https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2023/10/fair-play-movie-review-netflix/675489/)

The structure of the bold sentence is confusing to me. I've never seen a subject that follows **that + noun phrase**. I thought it means **the glossy skyscrapers involving house hedge funds and investment banks look too polished to contain American psychos and Wall Street wolves.** Is there any grammatical explanation for it? Or maybe I've misunderstood its structure?

Comment: It seems you haven't realised that [**house**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/house#Verb) is a **verb**. The segment "that house hedge funds and investment banks" is a [relative clause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses_2), "that" is the pronoun standing for "The glossy skyscrapers" and is the subject of  the verb "house". Main verb "look"

Comment: The words ***that house hedge funds and investment banks*** are effectively optional / parenthetical. First parse the sentence *without* those words, then take account of them separately (as text telling you more about the skyscrapers).

Comment: Just a note that the answers haven't mentioned - "house" as a noun rhymes with mouse. "House" as a verb has the same vowel but uses a z sound instead of the s, houze.

Answer (score 10):

Your confusion probably comes from the fact that you have not realised that, in the sentence you are quoting, the word [***house***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/house#dictionary-entry-2) is a verb.

◊ The main clause of the sentence is:

> The glossy skyscrapers look too polished to contain American psychos and Wall Street wolves. (a)

***look*** is the main verb of that clause.

◊ Additional information is given about these glossy skyscrapers:

> They house hedge funds and investment banks. (b)

Synonyms of *house* here could be *shelter* or *contain*. It means that in these skyscrapers there are "hedge funds and investment banks".

◊ (a) and (b) are blended into one single sentence containing a main clause (a) and a [relative clause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses_2) in which ***that*** is a [relative pronoun](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-pronouns?q=Relative%20pronouns%3A%20that)  referring to *the glossy skyscrapers*. *House* is the verb of the relative clause, the subject of *house* is *that*.

> The glossy skyscrapers **that house hedge funds and investment banks** look too polished to contain American psychos and Wall Street wolves.

Comment: Is there not a third verb here? We have _house_, _look_ and then _contain_. Am I right in thinking of 'to contain' as an auxiliary verb here?

Comment: Yes, you can drop everything after the "to" -- "The glossy skyscrapers look too polished" is a complete sentence -- I'm a little rusty on the formal analysis here but I think "to contain ..." is best described as a prepositional phrase modifying "too polished".  For what purpose are they too polished?  For the purpose of containing American psychos and Wall Street wolves.

Comment: @sdenham Yes, *contain* is a verb. It is not an auxiliary verb, it is the infinitive form of the verb. "to contain American  psychos ..." is a subordinate clause showing purpose, it is introduced by *to* (short for "in order to" which would be more formal). ['to' versus 'in order to'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11517/to-versus-in-order-to). [There](https://www.englishgrammar.org/order/) as well.

Comment: @zwol No, you can't "drop everything after the "to"", "to" is part of the subordinate clause (it is not a prepositional phrase), it introduces it. *The glossy skyscrapers look too polished* (main clause) / *to contain American psychos and Wall Street wolves* (subordinate clause).

Comment: @None You misunderstand, I meant to drop the "to" as well as everything after it.

Answer (score 4):

As indicated in the comments, *look* is the main verb.

*that house hedge funds and investment banks* is a relative clause defining *skyscrapers*.  This clause is restricted and is normally not separated by commas.

One reason for your misunderstanding is that you may not have realised *house* is a verb here.

Answer (score -2):

If I insert some commas, I think that it will be clear what the verb connected to the glossy skyscrapers is.

> The glossy skyscrapers, that house hedge funds and investment banks, look too polished to contain American psychos and Wall Street wolves.

In other words, the skyscrapers **look** too polished.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: the commas were solely intended to make it clear what the subordinate clause is. In real life, there is no need to insert a comma before 'that' so there's no need for the closing comma.

Comment: Does your point require that you specifically use commas to separate out that phrase, or would it be just as true if you used something else, like bold formatting, or, say the '|' character? It really looks like a non-defining relative clause, and that can only confuse learners. I suspect it's also attracting downvotes, if you care about those things